# In() Operator not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am completely new to SQL. While doing study I had found issue shown below.

When I execute query I get output as `125,130,131`. I am storing that output in `@issueid` variable.

```
declare @issueid varchar(100) 

set @issueid = (
    SELECT STUFF(
            (
                SELECT ','+convert(varchar,ism_id )
                FROM table where ism_group_name='TEST_COPY'
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ) ,1,1,''))
```

But when I use `@issueid` variable in below query I get weird behavior:

- If I pass `@issueid='125'` I get the results
- If I pass `@issueid='125,130,131'` it shows no output.

My query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    ISSUE_MASTER (NOLOCK), 
    ORDER_ENTRY_PPDI (NOLOCK) 
WHERE ISM_ID= OE_ISSUE_ID 
    and ism_id=oe_issue_id 
    and convert(varchar,oe_issue_id) in (@issueid) 
    AND ISM_STATUS = 0
GROUP BY ISM_ISSUER_NAME,ISM_ISSUE_NAME,OE_ISSUE_ID
```

Please help! What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why concat integer values as string when finally you want to use it for Integer datatype? Instead use table variable to capture issue id and then use it in your second query.

Comment: Is your variable `@issueid` needed somewhere else than the query you've provided? If not, I wouldn't store the values in a variable at all but join directly to your table `table`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic SQL for that particular problem, but as @Aquillo commented it is no good way. It is better to join the first table with tables you need, without making comma separated parameters:

```
SELECT  im.*,
        oe.*
FROM ISSUE_MASTER im (NOLOCK), 
INNER JOIN ORDER_ENTRY_PPDI oe (NOLOCK) 
    ON im.ISM_ID= oe.OE_ISSUE_ID  
INNER JOIN [table] t
    ON oe.oe_issue_id = t.ism_id
WHERE ISM_STATUS = 0  
    AND ism_group_name='TEST_COPY'
GROUP BY ISM_ISSUER_NAME,ISM_ISSUE_NAME,OE_ISSUE_ID
```

Another solution is to translate `@issueid` to table with the help of XML and eventually join it:

```
DECLARE @x xml

SELECT @x = CAST('<v>'+REPLACE(@issueid,',','</v><v>')+'</v>' as xml)

SELECT  im.*,
        oe.*
FROM ISSUE_MASTER im (NOLOCK), 
INNER JOIN ORDER_ENTRY_PPDI oe (NOLOCK) 
    ON im.ISM_ID= oe.OE_ISSUE_ID  
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT t.v.value('.','int') as ism_id
        FROM @x.nodes('/v') as t(v)
    ) t
    ON oe.oe_issue_id = t.ism_id
WHERE ISM_STATUS = 0  
    AND ism_group_name='TEST_COPY'
GROUP BY ISM_ISSUER_NAME,ISM_ISSUE_NAME,OE_ISSUE_ID
```

Dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

@sql = N'
SELECT * 
FROM ISSUE_MASTER im (NOLOCK), 
INNER JOIN ORDER_ENTRY_PPDI oe (NOLOCK) 
    ONim.ISM_ID= oe.OE_ISSUE_ID  
WHERE convert(varchar,oe_issue_id) in ('+@issueid+') 
    AND ISM_STATUS = 0  
GROUP BY ISM_ISSUER_NAME,ISM_ISSUE_NAME,OE_ISSUE_ID'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Note: use aliases, use new style join.

Comment: Though this would work, the approach is by far not the best way to deal with the given problem. I wouldn't recommend OP to implode multiple values only to search for a single value in the resulting string.

Comment: @Aquillo It is better to join the first table with target table, without making comma separated parameters. Or OP can translate `@issueid` to table with the help of xml and join it.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I mean. Though you have given an answer to OP's question, there is the problem of the 'wrong' (far from best) approach chosen by OP, which is not addressed in your answer.

Comment: @Aquillo add this to my answer, thanks for pointing on this issue.